# Are there ways to easily convert chapter-split books from popular fan-fiction sites into single e-book?

Tags: conversion, creation, html, website

Are there ways to easily convert chapter-split books from popular fan-fiction sites into single e-book?

Of course, one can either manually download every one of 50+ chapters of a large fic by hand and copy/paste them together, or write some Perl code to scrape the contents of the site.

But I'm hoping someone already came up with pre-packaged solution for at least the most popular sites like [FanFiction](https://www.fanfiction.net/) (if the general question is too broad, we can restrict it to the latter)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [GrabMyBooks](http://www.grabmybooks.com/) Firefox extension. It can grab single web-pages and convert them to epub, or adding multiple pages as distinct chapters.

There is also a Calibre plugin called FanFictionDownloader, but I've never used it.

Comment: The former seems pretty manual (it doesn't advance to the next chapter by itself, right?). I'll try the plugin, thanks!

Comment: Yes, you must manually add every single webpage. It's not specifically aimed at fanfiction sites but to general pages.